# JavaScript: better solution instead eval()

Tags: javascript

I have a class written in JavaScript called `populateTabs`. Inside a method I need to initialise different methods like:

- `populateTabs.facebookStatus();`
- `populateTabs.twitterStatus();`
- `populateTabs.googleStatus();`
- etc.

Instead of using conditionals or even a switch statement with multiple cases, I wanted to replace `facebook`, `twitter`, `google` with a parameter I have called `channelName`.

I had this options:

- `eval ( 'populateTabs.' + channelName + 'Status()' );` (**as I understood this is not proper use**)
- `populateTabs[channelName + 'Status'];` (**proper use**)

I've read that using `eval()` is not really recommended.

Is there a better and secure solution for my issue? Other than using switch statement or if conditionals. All this are subject of writing less code and I'm curious.

Comment: What's wrong with your second option?

Comment: The second solution (calling a function from an object) seems ok to me. Why not use that?

Comment: Please stop using `backticks` to highlight words. They're for marking up inline code, not adding emphasis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a better technique than `eval`, and you wrote it in your question:

> ```
> populateTabs[channelName + 'Status']; (proper use)
> ```

What more do you want? As you stated, this is the proper way of doing it.

Comment: Just being curious if there is even a better solution :D

Comment: No, there isn't. That's the canonical way of invoking a method whose name is stored in a variable.

Comment: Thank you. Now I'm calmed :)

Comment: populateTabs[channelName + 'Status'].apply();